# React ag-grid v28 creating button in a column with cellRenderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to create a edit button, like this link did: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-buck-6bkhw?file=/src/App.js
In the link also used ag-grid as a table component.

My problem; below code,it couldn't find type for params in `actionCellRenderer(params)`.
Ts complier gives an error "Parameter 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type." and when I look the types for AgGridReact coldef for cellRendererParams it says any, but any type causes problem in my code. Can you help me how to solve this type problem?

```js
export interface ColDef<TData = any> extends AbstractColDef<TData>, IFilterDef {
   ...
   /**
    * Provide your own cell Renderer component for this column's cells.
    * See [Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/) for framework specific implementation details.
    */
    cellRenderer?: any;
    /** @deprecated As of v27, use `cellRenderer` for framework components too. */
    cellRendererFramework?: any;
    /** Params to be passed to the `cellRenderer` component. */
    cellRendererParams?: any;
    /** Callback to select which cell renderer to be used for a given row within the same column. */
    cellRendererSelector?: CellRendererSelectorFunc<TData>;
    /** Set to `true` to have the grid calculate the height of a row based on contents of this column. Default: `false` */
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'; // Core grid CSS, always needed
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'; // Optional theme CSS
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import { CellClickedEvent } from "ag-grid-community";

const UserList: React.FC = () => {

    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(); // Set rowData to Array of Objects, one Object per Row


    function actionCellRenderer(params) {
        let eGui = document.createElement("div");
      
        let editingCells = params.api.getEditingCells();
        // checks if the rowIndex matches in at least one of the editing cells
        let isCurrentRowEditing = editingCells.some((cell) => {
          return cell.rowIndex === params.node.rowIndex;
        });
      
        if (isCurrentRowEditing) {
          eGui.innerHTML = `
      <button  class="action-button update"  data-action="update"> update  </button>
      <button  class="action-button cancel"  data-action="cancel" > cancel </button>
      `;
        } else {
          eGui.innerHTML = `
      <button class="action-button edit"  data-action="edit" > edit  </button>
      <button class="action-button delete" data-action="delete" > delete </button>
      `;
        }
      
        return eGui;
      }

    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'athlete', filter: false, minWidth: 150, editable: true },
        { field: 'age', filter: false, maxWidth: 90, editable: true },
        { 
            headerName: "action",
            minWidth: 150,
            cellRenderer: actionCellRenderer,
            editable: false,
            colId: "action"
         }
    ]);

        // Example load data from sever
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
                .then(result => result.json())
                .then(rowData => setRowData(rowData))
        }, []);



    return (
        <div>
            <AgGridReact
                rowData={rowData}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
            >

            </AgGridReact>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 0):

`params` in this case are `ICellRendererParams<TData = any, TValue = any>`, as per:

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#cell-renderer-component-2